# Как считать текстовый файл как словарь Python

Tags: python, словари

Всем привет, у меня есть словарь, который я вывел в файл. А сейчас нужно этот же файл считать так, чтобы содержимое считалось, как словарь, а не строка.
Полазим по сайтам, пока ничего не нашел.
Есть варианты:

```
f = open('text.txt', 'r')
l = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

Не работает, потому что далее я считываю его подобным образом:`for key, val in users.items():`

Словарь выглядит примерно так:
{11028522: 2, 46042277: 17, 398612226: 1033,............}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В питоне есть специальный модуль pickle, который позволяет сохранять в файл не только словари, но и другие структуры данных, а потом легко читать их из файла:

```
import pickle

data = {11028522: 2, 46042277: 17, 398612226: 1033}

# Сохраняем словарь в файл
with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)

# Читаем словарь из файла
with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
   data_new = pickle.load(f)

# Проверяем, что получился действительно словарь, а не строка
print(data_new[46042277])

# Получили результат '17'
```

Правда, в этом случае уже не получится открыть файл в текстовом редакторе и посмотреть глазами, что в нём лежит - pickle сохраняет данные в своём собственном формате, и внутри файла они будут выглядеть как набор бессмысленных кракозябр.

Если есть необходимость работать с этим файлом вручную, то можно сохранять данные как JSON с помощью соответствующего модуля.

```
import json

data = {11028522: 2, 46042277: 17, 398612226: 1033}

# Сохраняем словарь в файл
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data))

# Читаем словарь из файла
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
   data_new = json.loads(str(f.read()))
```

Но JSON годится только для словарей и списков, для более серьёзных объектов всё-таки нужно использовать pickle.