# python как добавить {'ключ':'значение'} в словарь, чтобы изменения остались в скрипте даже после выключения интерпритатора?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Имеется словарь:

```py
dict = {
    '1': 'one',
    '2': 'two',
}
```

По ходу программы добавляю новые `{'ключ': 'значение'}` в словарь:

```py
dict['3'] = 'three'
```

Но после выключения и включения программы, исчезают все новые элементы.

Как вносить изменения в словарь так, чтобы они остались при следующем запуске моей программы?

Comment: Сохранять в файл, а при запуске читать из него.

Comment: Мне удобно работать со словарем, при записи в .txt будут дополнительные сложности для использования в простой программе. может подробнее расскажите как сохранить в другом файле и какого формата чтобы словарь остался однострочным, и с ним легко было работать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702621/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c-python?rq=1

Comment: Похоже это мне подойдет, большое спасибо Эникейщик и Alexander Chernin.